# Creating a combined option in dimension

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dimension which is simply a list of user groups such as the below:

**User Type**

- Type A
- Type B
- Type C

I am currently visualising these as an individual pie for each user type with the numerical value shown in the middle which is their answer to a question from another measure. However, I'd like to create a fourth type which is 'All users' so that I have four pies showing at once: All Users, Type A, Type B and Type C.

Is this possible? Would it be a calculated field? I have tried groups but can't get it to work.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming for the moment that you have User Type on the Columns shelf, you can simply choose Totals->Show Row Grand Totals from the Analysis menu.

An alternate approach is to display two worksheets on the same dashboard. To do that, simply duplicate your worksheet. Remove User Type from the view in the new worksheet. And then place both views next to each other on a dashboard, possibly in a layout container to keep them lined up nicely. Format a bit to remove the titles and outside borders and they can look like one unit.

Remember what a dimension does. It **partitions** the data rows according to the value of the dimension field, assigning each data row to exactly one partition - exactly like a Group By clause does in SQL. So a data record can’t be associated with more than one member of a dimension. Totals behave differently, which is why they address your use case.

Comment: Thanks but because they are pies I don't have anything on rows or columns. I just added my filters and dragged user type onto color and then another one onto text label along with my answer field. This gives me a row of pies for each user group with the name and average number for all questions, each with a different colour. If I do the combined one on a new sheet like you suggested I end up with one bubble not fitting the colour scheme or showing up in the legend at the side along with the others. Ideally I want the legend to show 'all', 'type a', 'type b' and 'type c'. Is that not possible?

Comment: So I just tried doing analysis and show grand totals and it adds an extra bubble for all. Thanks!